# Convert Timestamp to str value python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have dataframe
which looks like this

```
    Date        Player          Fee
0   2017-01-08  Steven Berghuis 6500000
1   2017-07-18  Jerry St. Juste 4500000
2   2017-07-18  Ridgeciano Haps 600000
3   2017-01-07  Sofyan Amrabat  400000
```

I want to change every date value to str if they match the condition

```
def is_in_range(x):
ses1 = pd.to_datetime('2013-02-01')
ses2 = pd.to_datetime('2014-02-01')
ses3 = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-01')
ses4 = pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01')
ses5 = pd.to_datetime('2017-02-01')
ses6 = pd.to_datetime('2018-02-01')

if x < ses1 :
     x = '2012-13' 
if x > ses2 and x < ses3 :
     x = '2013-14'
if x > ses3 and x < ses4 :
     x = '2014-15'
if x > ses4 and x < ses5 :
     x = '2015-16'
if x > ses5 and x < ses6 :
     x = '2016-17'
return ses6
aj = ajax_t['Date'].apply(is_in_range)
aj
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        18          x = '2016-17'
>        19     return ses6
>   ---> 20 aj = ajax_t['Date'].apply(is_in_range)
>        21 aj
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py
>   in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    2353
>   else:    2354                 values = self.asobject
>   -> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    2356     2357         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
>   (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66645)()
>
> in is_in_range(x)
>        15     if x > ses4 and x < ses5 :
>        16          x = '2015-16'
>   ---> 17     if x > ses5 and x < ses6 :
>        18          x = '2016-17'
>        19     return ses6
>
> pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib._Timestamp.**richcmp**
>   (pandas/_libs/tslib.c:20281)()
>
> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

I get this error any suggestions,
Kindly

Comment: I think your `date` column may not be in datetime format? I don't know, it depends on your dataframe. If so, you will have to convert that `x` to datetime as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need convert to column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) if necessary and change variable `x` to another, like `y`, because is overwritten in loop.

Also variable `y` should be returned from function:

```
ajax_t['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ajax_t['Date'])

def is_in_range(x):
    print (x)
    ses1 = pd.to_datetime('2013-02-01')
    ses2 = pd.to_datetime('2014-02-01')
    ses3 = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-01')
    ses4 = pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01')
    ses5 = pd.to_datetime('2017-02-01')
    ses6 = pd.to_datetime('2018-02-01')

    if x < ses1 :
         y = '2012-13' 
    if x > ses2 and x < ses3 :
         y = '2013-14'
    if x > ses3 and x < ses4 :
         y = '2014-15'
    if x > ses4 and x < ses5 :
         y = '2015-16'
    if x > ses5 and x < ses6 :
         y = '2016-17'
    return y
aj = ajax_t['Date'].apply(is_in_range)
print (aj)
0    2015-16
1    2016-17
2    2016-17
3    2015-16
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `pd.cut`

```
ses1 = pd.to_datetime('2013-02-01')
ses2 = pd.to_datetime('2014-02-01')
ses3 = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-01')
ses4 = pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01')
ses5 = pd.to_datetime('2017-02-01')
ses6 = pd.to_datetime('2018-02-01')

pd.cut(df.Date,[ses1,ses2,ses3,ses4,ses5,ses6],labels=['2012-13','2013-14','2014-15','2015-16','2016-17'])


Out[1227]: 
0    2015-16
1    2016-17
2    2016-17
3    2015-16
Name: Date, dtype: category
```

Or

```
ses = pd.to_datetime(['2013-02-01','2014-02-01','2015-02-01','2016-02-01','2017-02-01','2018-02-01'])
pd.cut(df.Date,ses,labels=['2012-13','2013-14','2014-15','2015-16','2016-17'])
```

Comment: this is really nice. Got an edit. You can add it in your own words.

Comment: @Bharathshetty will keep it ~ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the formatting of the date:

```
ses1 = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-08', format='%Y%b/%d')
```

Comment: Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you did not load `Date` column as `DateTime` in your `DataFrame ajax_t`. Try to convert it

```
ajax_t['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ajax_t.Date)
```

Or if you load the DataFrame `ajax_t` from file, e.g., `data.csv` file, you may specify parameters to force parse `Date` column to be `DateTime` type.

```
ajax_t = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Hope this would be helpful.